# Determine the matrix for shearing along a given line.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine the matrix for shearing along the line $y=x$ in the xy-plane, with $k$ as proportional constant.

My attempt:

Shearing along a line, as I understand it, is where all points on the line is imaged on them selfs, all other points remain their perpendicular distance d from the line, but are shifted $k\cdot d$ parallel to the line. k is a constant and $k\cdot d$ is negative on one side and positive on the other side of the line.

I determined $A_1$ for shearin along the x-axis: $$A_1\hat{e_x}=\hat{e_x}$$$$A_1\hat{e_y}=k\hat{e_x}+\hat{e_y}$$
$$\Rightarrow A_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&k\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then determined $A_2$for rotating to $y=x$:

$$A_2\hat{e_x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{e_x}+\hat{e_y})$$$$A_2\hat{e_y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-\hat{e_x}+\hat{e_y})$$
$$\Rightarrow A_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus shearing along y=x should be $A_2A_1\vec{x}=\vec{y}$
$$A=A_2A_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1&k-1\\1&k+1\end{pmatrix}$$

This is not the answer in the book: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1-k/2&k/2\\-k/2&1+k/2\end{pmatrix}$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a transformation $T$ in a different basis is applied as $BTB^{-1}$ where $B$ is change of basis matrix. Here $T=A_1$, $B^{-1}=A_2$, $B=A_2^T$. Required transformation is $A_2^TA_1A_2$. First we go to rotated basis, apply shear transformation and then come back to original basis (to original coordinate system $x-y$).

Also $A_2$ is a rotation matrix. It should be normalized as
$$A_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Then what does the $A_2A_1$ matrix do to vectors in the plane?

Comment: $A_2A_1$ first shears along x-axis and then also rotates the plane. It is two transformations at once, not a single transformation. In the problem, you also want to undo the first rotation you carried out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is pretty late where I am and I think I need to sleep on this to grasp it. I will be back tomorrow and see if my mind wraps around this any better.

Comment: What is the difference of two transformations at once contra one single transformation.

Comment: Think about what's being asked. You only have to do shear, not rotation. You're both shearing and rotating.

Comment: oh I think I'm starting to understand. I was visualising a vector $\vec{u}$ and the x-axis creating a parallelogram, who's diagonal was the new image vector $\vec{u'}$. And when you rotate the x-axis to tangent the y=x line you have the same parallelogram  and the new vector $\vec{u''}$. The final destination is the same for shear vs shear and rotate, but the vector $\vec{u}$ it starts from is different, right?

Comment: I'm so happy that I realise how wrong I am :)